# How do I reference CSS variable in Tailwind to define a custom class?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to define a variable in a CSS file like this:

```
:root {
    --sidebar-width: 56;
}
```

I'd like to now refer to that in a component to define that component's width:

```
<div className="w-[var(--sidebar-width)]">
   <MySidebar>
</div>
```

This doesn't work.  What I'm trying to achieve is to add the `w-56` class to that component and to do so as a variable so that I can refer to that variable in several places. Is this possible and if so, how do I specify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's impossible.
Just do this instead:

```
:root {
    --sidebar-width: 56;
}

<div className="w-[calc(4px*var(--sidebar-width)]">
   <MySidebar>
</div>
```

1 tailwind unit is `4px`.